# Contact Form without ajax just php and html page

Tags: php, forms, submit

I have a simple Contact Form 
it works very freat but I want the result on the same page in a small box
just under the form
where the fail messages are coming and success too

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
    <div class="one_half">
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Name') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Name'; }" value="Name">
        <input name="alter" type="text" id="alter" size="3" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Alter') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Alter'; }" value="Alter">
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" onfocus="if(this.value == 'E-Mail') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'E-Mail'; }" value="E-Mail">
        <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="30" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Handynummer') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Handynummer'; }" value="Handynummer">
        <input name="facebook" type="text" id="facebook" size="200" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Facebook') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Facebook'; }" value="Facebook">
        <input name="instagram" type="text" id="instagram" size="200" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Instagram') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Instagram'; }" value="Instagram">
    </div>
    <div class="one_half last">
        <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="3" id="comments" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Nachricht') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Nachricht'; }">Nachricht</textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="send_message" id="submit" value="Senden"/>
</form>
```

and here the PHP file

```
<?php
    if (!$_POST) exit;

    if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];
    $alter = $_POST['alter'];
    $facebook = $_POST['facebook'];
    $instagram = $_POST['instagram'];

    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $comments = stripslashes($comments);
    }

    $address = "xxx@xxx.de";
    $e_subject = 'Contact from ' . $name;
    $e_body = "von: $name" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $e_reply = "Alter: $alter\r\nE-mail: $email\r\nHandynummer: $phone";
    $e_content = "Nachricht:\r\n$comments" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $e_links = "Facebook:\r\n$facebook\r\nInstagram:\r\n$instagram" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

    $msg = wordwrap($e_body . $e_links . $e_content . $e_reply, 70);

    $headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

    if (mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

        // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

        echo "<fieldset>";
        echo "<div id='success_page'>";
        echo "<h1>Bewerbung erfolgreich</h1>";
        echo "<p>Danke <strong>$name</strong>, deine Bewerbung wurde erfolgreich an uns gesendet</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</fieldset>";

    } else {
        echo 'FEHLER!';
    }
```

It works PERFECT

but it's always getting on a new site, no matter if error or success.

I want to add a small block under the form where all results are displayed

I hope u can help me.

I don't want ajax or something else. I just want it added like it is.

Comment: Ajax is the way to go, but if you don't want to use it, try a frame.

Comment: ajax is actually the easiest way to achieve it

Comment: is ajax easier ? i am not a good php coder. thanks

Comment: Your page would need to post back to itself, and then re-echo the form after postback, along with the message. But as others have said, AJAX is probably actually easier. What's your objection to using AJAX?

Comment: i am not good in reading or writing that heavy codes most way :) if ajax is easy and i can add my check routines too then its ok too

Comment: `get_magic_quotes_gpc` has been removed from PHP

Answer (score 2):

A solution for your problem might be to have in the same PHP file the logic with the form rendering. Doing this, the form action will be the same PHP file, so it will load the PHP code before rendering the form view. By that, you'll be able to render bellow the form whatever you want to according with the output from the sending email.

For example, take a closer look at the `$mailResult` variable:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'] ?? null;
$email = $_POST['email'] ?? null;
$phone = $_POST['phone'] ?? null;
$comments = $_POST['comments'] ?? null;
$alter = $_POST['alter'] ?? null;
$facebook = $_POST['facebook'] ?? null;
$instagram = $_POST['instagram'] ?? null;

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}

$address = "xxx@xxx.de";
$e_subject = 'Contact from ' . $name;
$e_body = "von: $name" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "Alter: $alter\r\nE-mail: $email\r\nHandynummer: $phone";
$e_content = "Nachricht:\r\n$comments" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_links = "Facebook:\r\n$facebook\r\nInstagram:\r\n$instagram" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$msg = wordwrap($e_body . $e_links . $e_content . $e_reply, 70);

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;
$mailResult = '';

if (isset($name, $email)) {
    if (mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {
        $mailResult = "<fieldset>";
        $mailResult .= "<div id='success_page'>";
        $mailResult .= "<h1>Bewerbung erfolgreich</h1>";
        $mailResult .= "<p>Danke <strong>$name</strong>, deine Bewerbung wurde erfolgreich an uns gesendet</p>";
        $mailResult .= "</div>";
        $mailResult .= "</fieldset>";
    } else {
        $mailResult .= 'FEHLER!';
    }
}
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title page!</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" name="contactform" id="contactform">
    <div class="one_half">
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30"
               onfocus="if(this.value === 'Name') { this.value = ''; }"
               onblur="if(this.value === '') { this.value = 'Name'; }"
               value="Name">
        <input name="alter" type="text" id="alter" size="3"
               onfocus="if(this.value === 'Alter') { this.value = ''; }"
               onblur="if(this.value === '') { this.value = 'Alter'; }"
               value="Alter">
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30"
               onfocus="if(this.value === 'E-Mail') { this.value = ''; }"
               onblur="if(this.value === '') { this.value = 'E-Mail'; }"
               value="E-Mail">
        <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="30"
               onfocus="if(this.value === 'Handynummer') { this.value = ''; }"
               onblur="if(this.value === '') { this.value = 'Handynummer'; }"
               value="Handynummer">
        <input name="facebook" type="text" id="facebook" size="200"
               onfocus="if(this.value === 'Facebook') { this.value = ''; }"
               onblur="if(this.value === '') { this.value = 'Facebook'; }"
               value="Facebook">
        <input name="instagram" type="text" id="instagram" size="200"
               onfocus="if(this.value === 'Instagram') { this.value = ''; }"
               onblur="if(this.value === '') { this.value = 'Instagram'; }"
               value="Instagram">
    </div>
    <div class="one_half last">
        <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="3" id="comments"
                  onfocus="if(this.value === 'Nachricht') { this.value = ''; }"
                  onblur="if(this.value === '') { this.value = 'Nachricht'; }">
            Nachricht
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="send_message" id="submit" value="Senden"/>
</form>
<?php echo $mailResult ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I would anyway avoid this kind of solution. I would approach this problem with AJAX.
In these solutions, we are mixing the logic with the rendering.

Comment: This might work I guess, but you really should explain your answer properly, not just dump code which other people (especially the person asking) might not immediately understand the important parts of.

Comment: what did u change ? u add the code on top of page and at bottom just the result ?

Comment: @ADyson you're 100% right. I updated my answer with some explanation above the code.

Comment: is there anything negative adding the php file on the top of the index.html ?

Comment: well, it would be better than having everything in the same file... but still, you'll have a variable `$mailResult` from that PHP file that you're going to use in the "view file". The problem is the coupling logic-view. In these scenarios, I would go for an MVC point of view.

Comment: ok did not understand anything :) like i told i am not that good coder :) pls gimme examples